# ng server is not outputing any css

Tags: css, angular

I'm using *@angular/cli* when I execute **ng server**
the css code doesn't show up in anyway on the webpage.

This is the angular-cli.json

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.18",
    "name": "botshop"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/metismenu/src/metisMenu.css",
        "./assets/css/sb-admin-2.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../systemjs.config.js",
        "../node_modules/core-js/shim.js",
        "../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js",
        "../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js",
        "../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "../node_modules/metismenu/src/metisMenu.js",
        "./assets/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }

    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting outputed .js files but not any css.
I have upgraded ng-cli to the latest version and I'm using the last nodejs LTS

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to do ng build --watch to get it to write to disk and also update with changes.

Comment: the build --watch only shows it handling js to .js.map

Comment: Nothing of css showed up

Comment: This is still an issue may be. I just discovered that from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3133